# Which E-commerce Platform works well with Flash Product Customization+Social?

Tags: wordpress, looking-for-a-script, ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

What's the best platform out there that is flexible enough to easily integrate this:

Custom Flash App

I would like customers to :

1 - Select a t-shirt from a gallery of artists. 
2 - Customize it ( using a Flash tool i created ) 
3 - Select a T-shirt size 
4 - Order it.

All this flash widget does is generate a JPG on the server. the ecommerce app should assign it to that Order/Customer, and add it to their shopping cart.

Social Features Customers should also be able to comment on the t-shirts and artist bios.

I was thinking of trying Wordpress plugins like Shopp or Getshopped or Cart66. ----- then BuddyPRess for social features. Or is Magento a better choice? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Magento Tshirt Design tool http://productsdesigner.com/magento-tshirt-design-tool

Video demo http://youtu.be/Ay4wduiDTA8

This company also has stand alone tshirt design applications

Answer (score -1):

This could help you:

1. Business Catalyst
2. Magento
3. PrestaShop
4. OpenCart
5. osCSS

Comment: This is just a bare list of some options. Business Catalyst isn't even a just store app but an entire all-in-one platform. Can you point to some documentation about any of these that more directly addresses the specific question?